# Update by rowid went in full scan

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I'm executing a simple update (Oracle 11g DB):

```
update t_table1
set (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) =
(
  select temp_field2,temp_field3,sysdate,0,0
  from t_table2
  where t_table2.t1_rowid = t_table1.rowid
)
where t_table1.rowid in (select /*+result_cache*/ t_table2.t1_rowid from t_table2)
```

where t_table2 contains more or less 10M of records.
In the execution plan I see a full table scan on t_table1 that take lot of time.

I suppose the cause is the *t_table2.t1_rowid = t_table1.rowid* where condition. Is it possible to avoid the full scan?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |                        |  9980K|   549M|   200M (25)|670:03:30 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | t_table1               |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH JOIN                  |                        |  9980K|   549M|   2036K (2)| 06:50:00 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | t_table2               |  9980K|    94M|  10624  (2)| 00:02:00 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | t_table1               |   420M|    23G|    532K (3)| 01:46:30 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| t_table2               |     1 |     22|       3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | t_table2_PK_1          |     1 |       |       2 (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How big is table1? If you want to update 10M rows in there, a FTS may very well be the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: you should share the `explain plan` of the query for a performance related question.

Comment: How many rows are being updated?  The full table scan may be minor compared to the overhead of the update.  Do you have an index on `table1(rowid)`?

Comment: The t_table1 have 400M or rows; I've and unique index on t_table2.t1_rowid, on t_table1 I've other indexes.